# How to fetch values from different dataframe without for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a main dataframe `df` and another dataframe `ext_map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'true': [1, 2, 3], 'billed': [104, 50, 256]})

    true     billed  
0    1         104   
1    2         50   
2    3         256   

ext_map = pd.DataFrame(data={'label':[3.1, 2.5, 3.5], 'mix':[100, 200, 300]})

    label    mix   
0    3.1     100
1    2.5     200
2    3.5     300
```

I want to create a `new_col` in `df` to fetch `label` for each row of `df` such that `df.billed` <= `ext_map.mix`. How can I achieve that without a `for` loop? `mix` column is always sorted in ascending order. (All other values here just samples.)

Expected Result

```
    true    billed  new_col
0    1       104      2.5
1    2        50      3.1
2    3       256      3.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
lower_limit = 0
ext_map_sorted = ext_map.sort_values('mix')
df['new_col'] = pd.cut(df['billed'], 
                       [lower_limit] + ext_map_sorted['mix'].tolist(),
                       labels = ext_map_sorted['label'])

print(df)
   true  billed new_col
0     1     104     2.5
1     2      50     3.1
2     3     256     3.5
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with the `direction='forward'`. The dataframes need to be sorted by the column you want to use to merge, and after use `sort_values`, `reset_index` and `drop` to get the expected output

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('billed'), ext_map.sort_values('mix'), 
                   left_on='billed', right_on='mix', 
                   direction='forward')\
       .sort_values('true')\
       .reset_index(drop=True)\
       .drop('mix', axis=1)

print (df)
   true  billed  label
0     1     104    2.5
1     2      50    3.1
2     3     256    3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x : ext_map[ext_map.mix > x['billed']]['label'].head(1).sum(), 1)
```

Here is the df after the above is run:

```
   true billed  new_col
0   1   104     2.5
1   2   50      3.1
2   3   256     3.5
```